# X axis label in Highcharts graph in Django app

Tags: django, highcharts

I have created Highcharts graph by this code:

```
def chart_data(request):

    dataset = DispatchPlan.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('scheduled_date')).values('month').annotate(
        c=Sum('weight')).values('month', 'c')

    chart = {
        'chart': {'type': 'column'},
        'title': {'text': 'Weight Dispatched by Months'},
        'series': [{
            'name': 'Months',
            'data': [{'name': row['month'], 'y': row["c"]} for row in dataset]
        }]
    }

    return JsonResponse(chart)
```

How can I add the X axis labels such that it shows month name instead of 0 and 1 ?

This is the one row of dataset from which the graph is plotted

```
{'month': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Kolkata' IST+5:30:00 STD>), 'c': 17600}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `strftime` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)) like that :

```
{'month': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Kolkata' IST+5:30:00 STD>).strftime("%B"), 'c': 17600}
```